# React with uniqid not generating id

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm making a todo list for my first react project. I'm using the uniqid generator for my todo object, but the way I currently have it set up is returning an id of '' instead of a random id. It seems to work if I set the todo state outside of the handleSubmit function, but I don't understand why it won't work as I have it now. I would truly appreciate any guidance on what I may be missing that's causing this problem. Thanks!

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import List from './components/List';
import React from 'react';
import uniqid from 'uniqid';

function App() {
const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);
const [todo, setTodo] = useState({
name: '',
complete: false,
id: ''
});
const [error, setError] = useState(false);

function handleChange(e) {
setTodo({
  ...todo,
    name: e.target.value,
});
}

function handleAdd(newTodo) {
setTodoList([
  ...todoList,
     newTodo
])
}

function handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (!todo.name) {
  setError(true);
} else {    
  handleAdd({
    ...todo,
       id: uniqid()
  })
setError(false);
setTodo({
  ...todo,
     name: ''
})
console.log(todo);
}
}

function handleDelete(id) {
const todoListItems = todoList.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
setTodoList(todoListItems);
}

function handleClear() {
setTodoList([]);
}
```

Comment: That's because by that time you will not get unique id, it takes some time. You can do one thing just store that unique id in a variable at the starting of your handleSubmit function, and pass that variable in handleAdd function and also in setTodo({...todo,name:'',id:uniqueIdVariable})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `uniqid()` seems to be correct, it is just that `setTodo` will update the value of `todo` in the next render of the component, but the following `console.log(todo)` in the same event block still only have the old value before the update.

A live example showing the unique ID generated: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-drojd4?file=src/App.js)

The above example also changed `handleChange` and `handleAdd` to the following format, so that the previous value can be used without potential conflicts.

```
function handleChange(e) {
  setTodo((prev) => {
    return { ...prev, name: e.target.value };
  });
}

function handleAdd(newTodo) {
  setTodoList((prev) => [...prev, newTodo]);
}
```

Also added a `useRef` to empty the `input` after submit, because the original implement cleaned the state value as `""`, but did not seems to do the same for `input`.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  ...

  setTodo((prev) => {
    return { ...prev, name: "" };
  });
  newTodoRef.current.value = "";
}
```

Hope this will help.